# how to compress archive in a new folder with Powershell (compress-archive)?

Tags: powershell, zip

I need create a zip file in a new folder but powershell `compress-archive` `destinationpath` do not force create folder.

My target is in a variable.

```
$Composant = "foo.bar/foo.bar.ImportMe"
```

And my powershel code is:

```
compress-archive -Path $outdirbuild/$Composant/* -DestinationPath "temp/OutilDeploiement/$($Composant).zip" -compressionlevel optimal -verbose
```

my error is:

```
Abandon :  The path 'temp\OutilDeploiement\foo.bar' either does not exist or is not a valid file system path.
```

Comment: You would need to create the folder before the command.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, How? because the directory(ies) and the name of the file are in the same variable. I am looking for how to cut to make the directory creation(s) precisely. I am not a Powershell developper.

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows? Just confirming because of the forward slashes `/`  on the path.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon, Windows

Answer (score 0):

This should work, le me know if not:

```
$source = Join-Path $outdirbuild -ChildPath $Composant\*
$destination = 'absolutepath\to\zipfolder'
$fileName = 'zipfile.zip'

if(-not(Test-Path $destination))
{
    New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory -Force > $null
}

$params = @{
    Path = $source
    DestinationPath = Join-Path $destination -ChildPath $fileName
    CompressionLevel = 'Optimal'
    Verbose = $true
}

Compress-Archive @params
```

- You can add `-Force` to compress without confirmation.
- Adding `\*` at the end of the source path you're not compressing the root folder, just confirming if this is what you want.

Comment: the problem is on `DestinationPath` not on `Path`. I probably need use `Join-Path` for `$destination` and `$fileName`

Comment: @StéphaneGRILLON right, I know, it should be working now. First `Test-Path` validates if the folder exists, if not, it creates the folder and then you join the folder absolute path with `$fileName` here: `DestinationPath = Join-Path $destination -ChildPath $fileName`

Comment: I do not have `$destination` and `$fileName` splited. I have path and file name in same variable `$Composant`